# Multi URL paramaters with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "database";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select database");


    $id = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['Day'])){ $id = (int)$_GET['Day']; }

    if(!$id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `TimeTable`";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `TimeTable` WHERE `Day`='".$id."'";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
or die(mysql_error());
    print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

This code worked previously, but has now stopped, and is producing **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR in /Directory/TimeTable.php on line 27**

I am also looking to add more parameters, (eg: Where `Day` = $id and `Year` = $Year )

Comment: The `or die(mysql_error());` has no place there. It was probably behind the `mysql_query()` previously

Comment: Stop using mysql_ functions. If you read the PHP manual its got a big red box saying WARNING - DON'T USE THIS! (basically) http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Start by removing `or die(mysql_error());` on line 28 - Edit: Damn you Pekka.

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked up the new mysql functions an have changed to mysqli.

```
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "database";

    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    $id= 0;
    if(isset($_GET['Day'])){ $id=(int)$_GET['Day']; }
    $year = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['Year'])){ $year=(int)$_GET['Year'];}

    if(!$id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TimeTable";
    } else {
        if (!year) {
        $query = "Select * FROM TimeTable";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM TimeTable WHERE Day=$id AND Year=$year";
        }
    }

    $rows = array();
    //Perform JSON encode
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
or die(mysql_error());
```

This is a syntax error, doesn't know what to do with that or die() statement. Change to this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Error');
}
while(...) {
}
```